# Swift Declared Typed Array from AnyClass object

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way in Swift to take an instance of `AnyClass` and use that to declare an array of that type?

For example, I'm using [Overcoat](https://github.com/gonzalezreal/Overcoat) and [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) to map JSON responses into models that are persisted in CoreData by the frameworks. Before I do a get request, I manually perform a fetch request on the Core Data context and receive back all the persisted models. I then have to use `MTLManagedObjectAdapter` which turns `NSManagedObjects` into plain models and back, to map the results from the fetch request into my model objects.

To that end, I made a function that I defined on the base model class:

```
class func mapResults(results: [NSManagedObject], toModelClass modelClass: AnyClass) -> ([AnyObject], [NSError?]) {
    var transformed: [AnyObject] = []
    var errors: [NSError?] = []
    for result in results {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var model: AnyObject! = MTLManagedObjectAdapter.modelOfClass(modelClass, fromManagedObject: result, error: &error)
        transformed.append(model)
        errors.append(error)
    }
    return (transformed, errors)
}
```

I would love to be able to declared `transformed` as `var transformed: [modelClass] = []` but for obvious reasons that doesn't work. Is there any way to convert that `AnyClass` object into a type or is it just not possible right now in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can use [Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html):

```
class Mapper {
    class func mapResults<T: AnyObject>(results: [NSManagedObject], toModelClass modelClass: T.Type) -> ([T], [NSError?]) {

        var transformed: [T] = []
        var errors: [NSError?] = []

        for result in results {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            var model: T = MTLManagedObjectAdapter.modelOfClass(modelClass, fromManagedObject: result, error: &error) as T
            transformed.append(model)
            errors.append(error)
        }

        return (transformed, errors)
    }
}
```

You can call this method like:

```
let (transformed, errors) = Mapper.mapResults(results, toModelClass: MyModel.self)
```

Moreover, according to `MTLManagedObjectAdapter.h`,

```
// modelClass    - The MTLModel subclass to return. This class must conform to
//                 <MTLManagedObjectSerializing>. This argument must not be nil.
```

So you should restrict `T` as `MTLModel` and conforms to `MTLManagedObjectSerializing`:

```
class func mapResults<T: MTLModel where T: MTLManagedObjectSerializing>(results: [NSManagedObject], toModelClass modelClass: T.Type) -> ([T], [NSError?]) {
```

Comment: This is fantastic, I had completely forgotten about generics.